# Why do these two expressions have different results

Tags: python

Why does Python yield different results when performing modulo calculations with values of different signs, such as `12426 % 10` resulting in `6` and `-12426 % 10` resulting in `4`, as well as `-856 % 10` resulting in `4` and `856 % 10` resulting in `6`? Shouldn't both examples yield a result of `6` for positive values *and* for negative values?

Comment: No. The easiest way to think about this is to think of a clock. Let's say it's 3, and you want to know what time it was 7 hours ago .. well `3-7 == -4` mod 12 is 8. Look at an analog clock face